# How to access local variable of method in angular 2 unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying write the unit test case for method in angular 2 with typescript. In that i have one local variable which is deciding which function will call.

```
getData(){
    let condition = route.queryParam.refer;
    if(condition === 'productWithChild'){
         this.LoadProductWithChildData(); 
    } else if(condition === 'product') {
         this.LoadProduct();
    }else{
        this.showMessage('No Data is Available');
    }
}
```

please suggest how to write unit test case for this method.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you are trying to test this. With your code, the `if()` statement is the only one that will ever be executed. Can you please post additional code so I can try and help better?

Comment: getData(){
        let condition = route.queryParams.refer;
        if(condition){
           // call method1 
        } else {
            // call method2
        }
    }

Comment: Can you edit your original post with this code so I can read it better? Thanks! :)

Comment: i am getting  `refer` from url queryparam. based on that deciding which method should called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Code to test:
getData(){
    let condition = route.queryParam.refer;
    if(condition === 'productWithChild'){
         this.LoadProductWithChildData(); 
    } else if(condition === 'product') {
         this.LoadProduct();
    }else{
        this.showMessage('No Data is Available');
    }
}

// Sample code, but not complete:
describe('getData()', () => {
  it('should call the LoadProductWithChildData() function when the route.queryParam.refer value is "productWithChild"', () => {
    // Mock your route.queryParam.refer value here.
    component.route = {
      queryParam: {
        refer: 'productWithChild'
      }
    };
    spyOn(component, 'LoadProductWithChildData');
    
    expect(component.LoadProductWithChildData)
      .toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  
  // Repeat the above for each of the conditions you have in your if()else() block.
});
```